# Update json field value to lower case in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which includes a json field. One of the key have mixed case values and I want to convert them to lower case. I have tried a few methods to do that,  but nothing works and raising explicit cast issues.

```
UPDATE table SET data = LOWER( CAST (data AS json)) WHERE id=123;
```

Above query raised the following error.

> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.

- I have also tried to update particular key but that also raised the same kind of error.
- I am not sure if PostgreSQL allowed such kind of operation on json data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lower()` is for type `text`. So first cast your json data into text. After `lower()` execution you can cast it back into type `json`:

```
UPDATE a SET data = LOWER(data::text)::json;
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Sp7gN6u)

Comment: Ohh Yes.. I tried this `UPDATE a SET data = LOWER(data::text)` but then data was of json type so didn't work .. but i can convert that back to json ..... Works like a charm .. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user5594493: this converts **everything** to lowercase, not only values, but also the keys.

Comment: yes, everything inside `data` but no worries my keys are already in lower case. Thx for the update though

Comment: @S-Man If we want for specific values corresponding to key ..is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

**Update json/jsonb field value to lower/upper & title case in Postgres**

> For lower case

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name =LOWER(column_name::text)::jsonb;
```

Without jsonb

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name =LOWER(column_name::text);
```

> For Upper case

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = UPPER(column_name::text)::jsonb;
```

> For Title case

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = INITCAP(column_name::text);
```